# Storing GPS data - GAE or in SQL LITE

Tags: google-maps, google-app-engine

I am developing a GPS application that tracks a user, sort of like the app Runkeeper that tracks where you have been on your run.

In order to do this, should I store GPS coordinates in a SQL Lite database on the phone or on Google App Engine and then when the user selects the data, I can send the entire set to the phone?

What would be a better design?

Answer (score 0):

I have a lot of experience in this category. I am also developing a similar app.  I save data on the phone, but periodically check for a connection and then upload the data to an app engine, and then delete the data on the phone (so it doesnt comsume too much phone memory).  I store upload files name to data store, and files to the cloud storage (which can accept larger size than the data store).  Then I upload the data to bigQuery for analysis and main storage of all data.  I also remember what data was successfully uploaded to bigQuery.  So there are really 4 memories just to get the data into BQ. Its quite an effort.  My next phase is doing the analytics using BigQuery and sending info back the phone app.  I also use Tableau as they have a good solution for reading bigQuery and they recognize geo data and you can plot lat,lon on an implementation of Open Street Map.

Certainly there are other solutions.  The downside to my solution is that the upload to bigQuery is slow, sometimes takes minutes before the data is available.  But on the other hand, Google's cloud tools are quite good and it integrates with 3rd party analytics/viewers.

Keep me updated on how you progress.